# Dojo fallbacks for IE9

Tags: javascript, css, dojo

I need some help with Dojo. The website that I'm working on is build using Dojo.
I need to make a fallback for css3 transitions/animations in IE9. It is required to use Dojo not jQuery. So, how can I implement a fallback using Dojo?

This is the css3 property that I have to do the fallback for:

```
div#mainNav.openSubNav, .openSubNav div#mainNav {
  -webkit-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  -o-transform: translate(300px, 0);
  transform: translate(300px, 0);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at 
http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojo/fx.html

It is all about animations...

Comment: Do you know If I can use dojo animations with classes instead of id??

Comment: Yes you can. fx expect a node, so if you pass a string it will do a getElementBy Id on that. However, you can pas a real node or the result of a dojo.query (where you can use css selectors)

Comment: I'm trying to do this, but it is not catching the node:
 on(dojo.query("a.uiLink"), mouse.enter, function(){
       
          domStyle.set(dojo.query(".uiLinkBar"), "backgroundColor", "red");
            fx.animateProperty({
              node: dojo.query("i.uiLinkBar"),
              properties:{
                width: 110
              },
              easing: easing.linear,
              duration: 400
            }).play();
        });

Comment: `dojo.query` returns a collection. You need to specify which node you want: `dojo.query('whatever')[0]` (for instance)